# Haskell - Array

Tags: arrays, haskell

I'm a newbie to Haskell, got stuck on a simple question:

```
aaa ::  [[(Char, Float)]] -> Float ->  [[(Char, Float)]]
aaa [[]] a = error "no indata"
aaa [[(a,b)]] c = [[(a, b/c)]] 
aaa inD c = ??
```

How to make it work with more than 1 element in Array?

Ex: `aaa [[('a',3)],[('b',4)],[('c',5)]] 4`

the result:  `[[('a',0.75)],[('b',1)],[('c',1.25)]]`

Any hint pls, thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define operations on lists as follows (I give you a simpler example that adds 1 to each list item)

```
f [] = []
f (head:tail) = (head + 1):(f tail)
```

I.e. `head:tail` represents a list; to be more specific, it represents the first list item (`head`) and the remaining list if we take the first item away (`tail`). Then, you usually apply your stuff to `head` and make a recursive call using `tail`.

Completing your example (without testing) this would yield:

`aaa ([(a,b)]:tail) c = [(a, b/c)] : (aaa tail c)`

One thing: You are dealing with a list and want to modify *each element of the list* in a specific way (but each element is transformed the same way). For such occasions, Haskell provides its intrinsic [`map`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/map_f.html) function, which takes:

- the function to transform a list items
- the list of items

as parameters and returns the transformed list.

Comment: Great, thx 4 help. A further question: if I got input like this: aaa [[('a',3),('b',4),('c',5)],[('a',3),('b',4),('c',5)]] 4   how to make this work?

Comment: @Ferry: You probably should open a new question for that.

Comment: @Ferry: Define a function that takes `[('a',3), ('b',5)]` (i.e. a single sublist) as argument and transforms it. Then, give this function as argument to `map`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, that `[...]` stuff denotes *lists*, not *arrays;* there is a fundamental difference between those two.

Try to think in terms of `fmap :: Functor a => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. This function takes another function and applies it over a data-structure. You could use it to implement your function. Here is a simple implementation. Try to understand it:

```
aaa l c = fmap (fmap (fmap (/c))) l
```